# Guzzle troubleshoot speed / slow

Tags: networking, guzzle

sorry in advance if my question is a little vague.

I have two servers, A and B
Guzzle on Server A tooks 1 sec to complete
Guzzle on Server B tooks 20 sec to complete

Both are on the same php version

Server A has 2G RAM Server B 1G RAM

What tools or testing script can I use to check why it is so slow on Server B?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

adding 'Connection' => 'close', in headers is fixing the issue